# Linear algebra formulation of an averaging

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have the following symmetric matrices $d$ and $m,$ whose elements are real and nonnegative, with their diagonals all zeroes:

$$d=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & d_{12} & d_{13}\\ 
  d_{21} & 0 & d_{23}\\
  d_{31} & d_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$

$$m=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & m_{12} & m_{13}\\ 
  m_{21} & 0 & m_{23}\\
  m_{31} & m_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I am trying to perform an averaging over different subsets of elements of $m$ based on values in $d:$ with the set of unique values in $d$ given by $u=\mathop{Set}\{d_{12},d_{13},d_{23}\}$ [*], there is an average $\langle m_i\rangle$ for $i\in u,$ such that $$\langle m_i\rangle=\frac{1}{n_i} \sum_{\{a,b\}|d_{a,b}=i}m_{a,b} $$

where for a given $i\in u$ the sum goes over all matrix indices $\{a,b\}$ where $d_{a,b}=i,$ and $n_i$ is the count of times value $i$ occurs in $d.$

[*]: for general square symmetric matrices $d$, $u$ is the mathematical set of entries in the upper or lower triangular part of $d.$

**Below is an example:**

---

$$d=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 5\\ 
  1 & 0 & 5\\
  5 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$

then $u=\{1,5\},$ $n_1=2,$ and $n_5=4$ and the corresponding means of $m$ are:

- $\langle m_1 \rangle= \frac{1}{2} (m_{12}+m_{21}),$
- $\langle m_5 \rangle= \frac{1}{4} (m_{13}+m_{23}+m_{31}+m_{32}).$

---

**Question:**

- Is there a linear algebraic way of expressing the $\langle m_i\rangle$'s in terms of $d$ and $m?$ For instance, by considering ways of partitioning the entries of $m$ matrix based on $d$ and taking the matrix product with an appropriately defined matrix to obtain $\langle m_i\rangle $ as columns or rows of the resulting matrix.

To clarify better what I mean by *linear algebraic formulation*, here's an example: To compute the sum of all entries in a matrix $A,$ we can use the product: $\mathbf 1^\top\mathbf A\mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the column vector of all ones, which makes the task computationally very efficient.

Comment: You can split  $d_ab$ into $D_{a,b,i}$ where all entries are  $1,0$ and each $i$ index represents the average you want to calc, for example $D_{a,b,5}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1\\ 
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$ and then calculate$ <m_5>=\sum_{a,b} D_{a,b,5}m_{a,b}$

Comment: @user721481 Hi, You might be onto something here! But wouldn't we in that approach just be doing the whole sum? I mean there's no linear algebra short-cut to make it more efficient there, unless I've missed something in what you meant by $D_{a,b,5}m_{a,b}.$

Comment: I'm not sure what the use of the averaging approach is, because if you're just isolating a fixed number $a$ and that number repeats itself $n$ times in the matrix, you seem to just be computing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a = a$.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @Mnifldz no the averaging is done over the elements of the other matrix, $m,$ whereever the elements of matrix $d$ were the same. See please the included example, it showcases better than my explanation.

Comment: @user929304 Oh, ok.  I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to do this using linear algebra is to use the Euclidean norm of matrices: $\langle A, B\rangle = \text{Tr}(A^TB)$.  The specific way that I would construct this would be the following: Once you identify the distinct parts of $d$ that you want to isolate, split the matrix up into its distinct parts.  Using your example:

$$
d \;\; =\;\; \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 5\\ 
  1 & 0 & 5\\
  5 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \;\; =\;\; \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0\\ 
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{ = E_1} + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 5\\ 
  0 & 0 & 5\\
  5 & 5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{=E_5}.
$$

Then if we compute $\langle \frac{1}{5}E_5, m\rangle$ we will get:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left \langle \frac{1}{5}E_5, m \right \rangle & = & \text{Tr} \left [\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1\\ 
  0 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & m_{12} & m_{13}\\ 
  m_{21} & 0 & m_{23}\\
  m_{31} & m_{32} & 0
\end{pmatrix}  \right ] \\
& = & \text{Tr} \left [\begin{pmatrix}
m_{31} & m_{32} & 0 \\
m_{31} & m_{32} & 0 \\
m_{21} & m_{12} & m_{13} + m_{23} \\
\end{pmatrix} \right ] \\
& = & m_{13} + m_{31} + m_{23} + m_{32}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The most general way to accomplish this then is to compute
$$
\langle m_k\rangle \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{k\cdot n_k} \text{Tr}\left (E_km\right ).
$$

Comment: I don’t see why that should be computationally difficult.  You don’t need looping in order to pick off the entries that have a certain value.  Even Matlab has built-in commands to pick off the correct entries that should work just fine independent of the size of the matrix.

Comment: Oh wow! Do you have an example in Matlab? I mean, irrespective of the language, I just thought we'd have to conditionally replace all entries that are not equal to the desired one, and put them to zero. And this kind of replace-all type of operations generally tend to be quite slow (even without looping, and solely using functional approaches).